# Proper way to implement S3 dispatch on R6 classes

Tags: r, r-s3, r6

I have an `R6` class and I want to add an `S3` method for it.  The documentation I found mentioned briefly that in order to use `S3` dispatch on `R6` you must have `class = TRUE`, but I couldn't find an example of how it should be done.

I did see empirically that simply writing an S3 method in the form `s3generic.r6class` worked, but I wanted to know if that is indeed to right way to write an `S3` method for `R6`.

For example, say I have an `R6` class that enhances a `list`

```
library(R6)

R6list <- R6Class(
  "R6list",
  public = list(
    orig = NULL,
    initialize = function(x) {
      self$orig <- x
    }
  )
)
```

**Question 1**

Naturally, I want to provide a method for obtaining the underlying list, so I wanted to add an `as.list` method. Is it standard to add both an S3 generic AND a `as.list` public function inside the class?  My intuitive answer is to add both.

```
R6list <- R6Class(
  "R6list",
  public = list(
    orig = NULL,
    initialize = function(x) {
      self$orig <- x
    },
    as.list = function() {
      self$orig
    }
  )
)

as.list.R6list <- function(x, ...) {
  x$as.list()
}
```

So that now if I have an object `mylist <- R6list$new(as.list(letters[1:5]))` I can either call `as.list(mylist)` or `mylist$as.list()`.  Is one of those preferred over the other?

**Question 2**
Is there anything special about writing an `S3` method for `R6` classes, or is what I wrote above sufficient and the correct way? I wasn't sure if the `S3` method has to be written outside of the class definition, or if `R6` somehow provides a way to write `S3` methods within it so that all the code relating to the class is localized.

Comment: The default for R6Class is  `class=TRUE`, so in a sense all of the examples you see are illustrations of such usage.

Comment: Right, `class=TRUE` is the reason my code above works, but I didn't see any examples explicitly showing how to write an S3 method so I'm wondering if this is the recommended way of doing this

Comment: The official answer (as of right now at least) is that what I'm doing is correct.  https://github.com/wch/R6/issues/42

Comment: so please write it as an answer, otherwise your question still appears in the unanswered ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked Winston Chang, the author of `R6`, about this [on Github](http://github.com/wch/R6/issues/42).  According to him, the code provided in Question 1 above is the correct way of writing S3 methods for R6 classes.