# Implementing method dispatch for a R6 class vector

Tags: r, r6, method-dispatch

Is there any guidance on how to implement method dispatch for a vector of R6 objects into a dataframe or list?

This works beautiful for single R6-classes

[Proper way to implement S3 dispatch on R6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117585/proper-way-to-implement-s3-dispatch-on-r6-classes)

Implementing S3 method dispatch as suggest in another thread works great for single R6 objects e.g.:

```r
R6list <- R6Class(
  "R6list",
  public = list(
    field1 = "A",
    field2 = "B",
    initialize = function(x,y) {
      self$field1 <- x
      self$field2 <- y
    },
    as.list = function() {
      list(
        "field1" = self$field1,
        "field2" = self$field2
      )
    }
  )
)

as.list.R6list <- function(x, ...) {
  x$as.list()
}

mylist1 <- R6list$new("A","B")
mylist2 <- R6list$new("1","2")
as.list(mylist1)
```

But how should something like the following could be implemented:

```r
as.list(c(mylist1,mylist2))
```

The returned data frame should have a row for every R6 object and the field names, should be used as column names with their values in every row